# 'Just' as adverb and…?

Tags: adverbs, intensifying-adverbs

"If you would just listen for a moment…"

"If you would listen just for a moment…"

Subtly different meanings, but in both cases 'just' is adverbial. In the first sentence, 'just' modifies listen. In the second, I think the whole phrase 'just for a moment' is adverbial, but no matter. 'Just' is moving around as you would expect from an adverb.

But what about "If you would listen for just a moment…"

'Just' is no longer modifying 'listen'. It isn't behaving like an adjective, it doesn't really modify 'a moment'. Yes, we can call it an adverb, given that 'adverb' is a bit of a catch-all category. But what is it really, what is it doing, what is it modifying? It doesn't really modify anything specific, it modifies the whole situation. It's more like a kind of intensifier or attitudinal word.

Does someone have a clear grammatical or linguistic analysis of this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Just' is no longer modifying 'listen'. It isn't behaving like an adjective, it doesn't really modify 'a moment'. Yes, we can call it an adverb, given that 'adverb' is a bit of a catch-all category. But what is it really, what is it doing, what is it modifying? It doesn't really modify anything specific, it modifies the whole situation. It's more like a kind of intensifier or attitudinal word.

That's not quite right, but I think I see what you're getting at.

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL) treats *just* as an adverb, and says that it functions in this case as a "focusing modifier", meaning that it applies semantically to an element that's then called the "focus". This may be what's leading you astray; in an example like "I just need one of them", *just* is syntactically modifying the verb phrase "need one of them", but semantically it clearly applies only to "one of them" or "one". Your example isn't a very compelling one IMHO — I think that "a moment" is both the (syntactic) head and the (semantic) focus — but I guess you're interpreting the focus to be "you would listen for a moment"?

Incidentally, the CGEL points out that although focusing modifiers can modify complete noun phrases, as in "just a moment", they can't modify a noun or nominal that's only part of a noun phrase, as in *"a just moment". This helps justify the "adverb" classification. (Of course, there's also an adjective *just* meaning "fair", and "a just moment" is possible with that sense.)

(Source: the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, chapter 6, §7.3 "Focusing modifiers", pp. 586–7.)

Comment: What other focusing modifiers does the CGEL list?

Comment: And semantically, I would struggle to define 'just'. It doesn't have the same sense as 'only', although it is close. It has the sense of 'it's not that hard' or 'it's a trivial thing' and often 'what's your problem?' but all the dictionary definitions I looked up fall short. (But maybe it's the 'If you would just' combination that gives this sense.)

Comment: Re: "What other focusing modifiers does the CGEL list?": *Alone*, *also*, *as well*, *but*, *even*, *exactly*, *exclusively*, *in addition*, *merely*, *only*, *precisely*, *purely*, *simply*, *solely*, and *too*. Per CGEL, all of these are adverbs, except for *in addition*, which is a prepositional phrase. It lists the majority of these as "restrictive" focusing modifiers on page 587; it lists the rest as "additive" focusing modifiers on page 592.

Comment: Not 'actually'? As in, "Actually, I think I know the answer". Or is 'actually' here something different again?

Comment: @Dunsanist: It doesn't list *actually*, though it also doesn't promise that its list is complete. FWIW, *actually* seems no different to me than any other sentence adverb -- *honestly*, *frankly*, *currently*, *seemingly*, *fortunately*, etc., etc.

Comment: Okay, so the example I gave was bad. How about, "I can't believe you actually ate that." ? Maybe that's not considered good usage, but it's common usage. Whereas in "He is actually fifty years old" you could probably consider 'actually' a simple adverb to 'is'. Which is an interesting point--that depending on placement, the adverb can actually work in several different ways.

Comment: @Dunsanist: Same thing IMHO -- "I can't believe you honestly/seriously/really ate that."