# Looking for sources and references for the adjective "just" (apart from meanings related to "justice" or comparison)

Tags: idioms, intensifying-adverbs

I'm interested in the implied meaning of the word "just" apart from things related to "justice" or comparison/near-comparison ("just in time", "just missed it"), e.g. Just Do It. The most common form of "just" I investigate is a synonym for "only", but that word has far less implication

I find that almost every use (by myself included) of this meaning of "just" has an implication ranging from belittlement to full-on temper-tantrum

- Just do what I tell you
- I just want some peace and quiet
- That's just an excuse
- Why can't this thing just work!

The theme seems to be: I want things to be my way without regard for other people, reasonableness, or reality

The O.E.D. (1971) has nothing of this meaning at all. Wiktionary has the non-implicit meanings as sentence adjectves. I have not bought the [CGEL](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367312/just-as-adverb-and), but I will if that's the only thing that talks about it

Other references and examples welcome

Cheers

Comment: Well, there's [this paper from CLS 5](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/cls/pcls/1969/00000005/00000001/art00003)

Comment: Thank you! That gives great information about the etymology of "just" I don't see it covering the modern idiomatic uses itself; I think its references might lead to other good sources

Comment: Just = merely, as one possibility.

Comment: You uses of just are adverbs, not adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/just) touches upon this in two of its definitions of ***just***:

> ***Just** for emphasis*
> We also use *just* to emphasise an imperative:
>
> - ***Just*** shut the door quickly or we’re going to be late. (similar to your 1st example)

> ***Just** to soften expressions*
> We use *just* in speaking to soften what we say, especially in requests:
>
> - Could you ***just*** open the window?

***Just*** is part of quite a few idiomatic expressions,<sup>1</sup> one of which is ***just sayin'***. [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/04/just-sayin.html) has an interesting article about it of which I will quote this:

> The expression “Just sayin’ ” follows an *irritating* or *annoying* or otherwise *unpleasant* observation. The speaker seems to imply that simply adding “Just sayin’ ” makes everything all right.
>
> Well, it doesn’t.
>
> We briefly referred to this stand-alone expression in a post we wrote a year ago on a similar usage sometimes referred to as a *“false front,” “wishwasher,” “but head,” or “lying qualifier.”*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just) has quite a few definitions of *just*, of which some are labelled as *[emphasis]*.

> You use ***just*** to indicate that something is no more important, interesting, or difficult, for example, than you say it is, especially when you want to *correct a wrong idea* that someone may get or has already got.
> [emphasis]
>
> - It's ***just*** a suggestion.
>
> You can use ***just*** in front of a verb to indicate that the result of something is *unfortunate or undesirable and is likely to make the situation worse rather than better*.
>
> - Leaving like I did ***just*** made it worse.
>
> You use ***just*** to emphasize the following word or phrase, in order to express feelings such as *annoyance, admiration, or certainty.*
> [emphasis]
>
> - She ***just*** won't relax. I don't see the point in it really. It's ***just*** stupid.(annoyance)
> - I knew you'd be here. I ***just*** knew. (certaninty)
> - Isn't he ***just*** the most beautiful thing you ever saw? (admiration, affection)
>
> You use ***just*** with instructions, polite requests, or statements of intention, *to make your request or statement seem less difficult*.
> [spoken]
>
> - I'm ***just*** going to ask you a bit more about your father's business.
>    <sub>*(That's the softening Cambridge was speaking about)*</sub>

And the list goes on. In conclusion, yes, it seems that *just* can be used as a marker of mood, softener or intensifier.

As For CGEL, as shown in the *[link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367312/just-as-adverb-and)* provided by @Xanne, it classifies this use of ***just*** as a ***focusing modifier***. In the next pages the restrictive adverb ***only*** is interpreted grammatically and semantically in detail (mentioning that *simply, merely, just* are its synonyms). It classifies focus in

> - ***Scopal*** (They ***only*** gave me a SANDWICH for lunch.)
> - ***Informational*** (***Only*** Kim preferred the ORIGINAL version.)

However, I don't see CGEL dealing with these other layers of meaning present in ***just***, about which you speak about.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Such as](https://www.learn-english-today.com/vocabulary/expressions-just.html) ***just about***, ***it's just that...***, ***just like that***, ***let's just say***, ***just as well***, ***just in case*** etc.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

From AHD: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=just

adv. (jəst, jĭst; jŭst when stressed)

1. Precisely; exactly: just enough salt.
2. Only a moment ago: He just arrived.
3. By a narrow margin; barely: just missed being hit; just caught the bus before it pulled away.
4. At a little distance: just down the road.
5. Merely; only: just a scratch.
6. Simply; certainly: It's just beautiful!
7. Perhaps; possibly: I just may go.

Comment: As we can see, the word *just* is an all-round favorite, and neutral as they come. Using it often in a fed up and bitchy tone does not make the word a villain. No built-in belittlement or  anger.

Comment: This question references CGEL: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367312/just-as-adverb-and